# Uncategorized SQLException Jdbc Template

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I'm attempting to call a stored procedure to create an item in a SQL table. When the code is run, the stored procedure is run and the item is created, but throws this error. The values stored in the table are correct and the generate key generates the correct key.

Here is my create function where I create the parameter map:

```
public int create(Job job) throws DataAccessException, NullPointerException {
    Assert.notNull(job,"Job must not be null.");
    Assert.notNull(job.getSite(),"Site must not be null."); 


    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    final String columnNames[] = {"id"};

    MapSqlParameterSource params = params("intSiteId",job.getSite().getId())
            .addValue("dtmStart", job.getStartDate() == null ? null : dateTimeString(job.getStartDate()))
            .addValue("dtmEnd", job.getEndDate() == null ? null : dateTimeString(job.getEndDate()))
            .addValue("intManualFl",job.isManual());

    getTemplate().update(getSql("create"), params, keyHolder, columnNames);


    return keyHolder.getKey().intValue();
}
```

update function that is in the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate Class

```
@Override
public int update(
        String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource, KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder, String[] keyColumnNames)
        throws DataAccessException {

    ParsedSql parsedSql = getParsedSql(sql);
    String sqlToUse = NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(parsedSql, paramSource);
    Object[] params = NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(parsedSql, paramSource, null);
    List<SqlParameter> declaredParameters = NamedParameterUtils.buildSqlParameterList(parsedSql, paramSource);
    PreparedStatementCreatorFactory pscf = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sqlToUse, declaredParameters);
    if (keyColumnNames != null) {
        pscf.setGeneratedKeysColumnNames(keyColumnNames);
    }
    else {
        pscf.setReturnGeneratedKeys(true);
    }
    return getJdbcOperations().update(pscf.newPreparedStatementCreator(params), generatedKeyHolder);
}
```

Exception:

> May 28, 2015 11:17:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call usp_createNewTrans(?,?,?,?)}]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; A result set was generated for update.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A result set was generated for update.] with root cause
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A result set was generated for update.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:417)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$3.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:946)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$3.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:943)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:943)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:344)
>       at com.crown.datapoint.services.dao.JobDAO.create(JobDAO.java:94)
>       at com.crown.datapoint.services.JobService.create(JobService.java:91)
>       at com.crown.datapoint.web.controller.JobRestController.createJob(JobRestController.java:63)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

## EDIT:

I modified my code to this (see below) and it works again... I return 0 to the restController which initially shows the id as 0... but then resolves to the correct id upon page refresh, but I feel like this isn't exactly the solution.

```
public int create(Job job) throws DataAccessException, NullPointerException {
    Assert.notNull(job,"Job must not be null.");
    Assert.notNull(job.getSite(),"Site must not be null."); 


    MapSqlParameterSource params = params("intSiteId",job.getSite().getId())
        .addValue("dtmStart", job.getStartDate() == null ? null : dateTimeString(job.getStartDate()))
        .addValue("dtmEnd", job.getEndDate() == null ? null : dateTimeString(job.getEndDate()))
        .addValue("intManualFl",job.isManual());

    getTemplate().update(getSql("create"), params);


    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when I called other stored procedures. I changed my method in calling the stored procedure to the following and it seems to work. I'm not entirely sure how the doInPreparedStatement works, so there is probably a better way to use that, but this seems to have solved my problem.

```
 public int create(Job job) {
    Assert.notNull(job,"Job must not be null.");
    Assert.notNull(job.getSite(),"Site must not be null.");


    MapSqlParameterSource params = params("intSiteId",job.getSite().getId())
            .addValue("dtmStart", job.getStartDate() == null ? null : dateTimeString(job.getStartDate()))
            .addValue("dtmEnd", job.getEndDate() == null ? null : dateTimeString(job.getEndDate()))
            .addValue("intManualFl",job.isManual())
            .addValue("insertDate",dateTimeString(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)));

    getTemplate().execute(getSql("create"), params, new PreparedStatementCallback<Boolean>(){
        @Override  
        public Boolean doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps)  
                throws SQLException, DataAccessException {   

            return 0;   
        }  
        });
   return (int)params.getValue("intSiteId");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you ask server side traces or reproduce it on a server where traces can be enabled? Because what is an unknown error on the client side could be logged in more specific way on your SQL Server server.